# alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, uialertview, ios4

The problem is only happening with iOS4.3. I'm using ARC and my Base SDK is iOS6.

In `-viewDidAppear` of my view controller, I check if this is the first time the app has been started and if so, then I create and show a UIAlertView. I assign that UIAlertView to a `strong` property on the view controller and set self as the UIAlertView delegate.

```
self.uiAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Welcome!"
                                              message:messageString 
                                             delegate:self
                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                    otherButtonTitles:@"View Tutorial Videos", @"Email Support", nil];
```

When I tap one of the buttons, the app crashes complaining that `-alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` was sent to a deallocated instance. The delegate is the view controller that is displaying the UIAlertView.

On all subsequent launches of the app, when the UIAlertView isn't shown there are no problems. The view controller is definitely not being deallocated.

If I display the UIAlertView but set the delegate to nil, then there is no problem and the app continues working, so clearly the view controller hasn't been deallocated because I can keep using it.

What is happening? This only causes a problem with iOS4.3.

EDIT: Based on suggestions in the comments, I added some more log messages in different places.

I've discovered that the view controller IS getting dealloc'd, but only if that view controller displays the UIAlertView. What in the world would cause the view controller to get dealloc'd just because it sets itself as the delegate of a UIAlertView and then displays it?

My app delegate has a `strong` reference to the view controller, so there is absolutely no reason  that I can see for the view controller to get dealloc'd.

---

EDIT 2: I've discovered that during start up my main view controller is being instantiated TWICE. The first one is the one creating the UIAlertView and that one is getting dealloc'd. The second one is the one that I've been able to interact with afterwards that made me think the view controller was still there and operable.

However, I can't figure out where or why my view controller would be created twice. I don't have any alloc/init statements for the view controller. It only exists in the MainWindow_iPhone.xib.

The first time viewDidLoad is called on my view controller, the stack frame above is [UIViewController view]. The second time viewDidLoad is called on the second instance of my view controller, the stack frame above is [UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]

---

EDIT 3: I've "fixed" the problem, but I don't understand why this would happen. Perhaps you can help me understand.

In my MainWindow_iPhone.xib, I created my root view controller and assigned it to an IBOutlet on my app delegate. Instead, I deleted the view controller from the xib and created it in code in the `-application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` ... and the problem disappeared.

Why in the world would the view controller be created twice when in the xib?

Comment: You have to show a bit more code, as the problem shown by you seems that whatever self is, is indeed deallocated when you click the OK button

Comment: But if I simply don't show the UIAlertView, the view controller works perfectly and is never deallocated. If I just comment out the [self.uiAlertView show]; call then it works. So what could even cause the currently visible view controller to be deallocated. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: If it happens only on iOS 4.3 it's probably a bug. Let's find a workaround. First, try to nslog and check if the delegate is correctly set.: NSLog(@"This VC: %@ - Alert Delegate: %@", self, self.uiAlertView.delegate) immediately after the uiAlertView allocation. In the result you should have, obviously, the same instance for self and the alert delegate. If not the same (ex: self.uiAlertView.delegate is nil), try to set it again directly: self.uiAlertView.delegate = self; and nslog again

Comment: When I log the delegate after alloc/init it is correct. I also set up a GCD call to log it again after 3 seconds. When I tap the OK button after that and I get the `-[MyViewController alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7b37600` error.. the class in the error is the RIGHT class. So, it's clearly pointing at the correct memory location and that view controller is there and is working... but when the UIAlertView tries to call didDismissWithButtonIndex, it think it's dealloc'd.

Comment: I added a log message to dealloc on my view controller and it is definitely getting called... but it's only called when I display the UIAlertView. WTF? How could showing a UIAlertView cause the presenting view controller to be dealloc'd?

Comment: Found the problem, but I don't understand it. Perhaps you understand. Check Edit #3.

Answer (score 1):

I have this issue before. alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex: is called after alertView: clickedButtonAtIndex:. You most likely deallocate the view controller in alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex by doing something like [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES].

UIAlertView delegate is assign not weak reference. When delegate is deallocated, it is not set to nil automatically. That's reason why your code is crashed.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed this issue commenting this method (or deleting it).

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSLog(@"se apreto cancel");
}
```

as James Wang said, the didDismissWithButtonIndex is called after clickedButtonAtIndex so i commented it to avoid the crash.