# Root View Controller is getting created twice

Tags: ios, xib, ios4

I've been fighting with a [crash from a message being sent to a dealloc'd instance.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146101/alertviewdiddismisswithbuttonindex-message-sent-to-deallocated-instance)

It turns out that my root view controller is getting created twice in iOS4.3. In `MainWindow_iPhone.xib` I create my root view controller and connect it to an IBOutlet on my AppDelegate. Two instances of my root view controller were getting created causing problems in my app.

I removed the root view controller from the `MainWindow_iPhone.xib` and instead created the root view controller in code in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and the problem disappeared. Only one instance of my root view controller is now being created.

Why the heck would two copies get created when I make it inside the `MainWindow_iPhone.xib`?

Comment: Uhm, strange. Lesson learned: create UI from code. IB is confusing.

Comment: How are you "making it inside" `MainWindow_iPhone.xib`? You have to show us your setup code.

Comment: I'm not doing it in code. I've added a UIViewController object to my xib and set it's class type to that of my view controller.

Comment: Then, how did you designate that controller as your window's root view controller?  You should post your code in the applicationDidFinishLaunching method.

Comment: By connecting the Window's rootViewController IBOutlet to my view controller. That's how the xibs are supposed to work. The appDidFinishLaunching code was simply a call to [window makeKeyAndVisible].